# What is the exact meaning of 着 and how to use it in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, usage, synonyms, syntax

What is the exact meaning of 着 and how can I use it in a sentence?

Comment: There are many shades of meaning. An exhaustive answer would be very long. Why don't you find a sentence where you don't understand 着 and ask about that?

Comment: How about 真的愛你 & 真的愛着你?

Comment: In that case 着 is redundant. You can remove it safely.

Comment: There is a song title 真的愛着你. So, it may not be redundant. In 真的愛你, it is ambiguous as to whether the love is still ongoing as it merely declares a state of love, as it were, without a time-stamp. However, in 真的愛着你, to borrow English grammar, it could be described as a "present perfect continuous tense", i.e., to talk, or emphasize about ongoing events or activities which started at a time in the past and are still continuing up until now. The song, 真的愛着你, is here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wW97iq_VrNI So, removing 着 may lose the time element emphasis.

Comment: There are many use of 着, but I'll give you the most common one. Usually, if it is added after a verb, it is like indicating an action that is currently happening of continuous, like 拉着 = pulling [拉着朋友的手奔跑 = pulling friend's hand to run], 接着 = carry on (v)/ after that (adv) [拉着朋友的手，接着在晚霞天空下奔跑 = pulling friend's hand, and then run under the sky with rosy cloud]

Answer (score 1):

Good question! You get on something small, yet complex. Allow me to put an list here, and get back to it later:

听**着**(zhe): 
     Listen!

看**着**(zháo)了: 
     Have seen, saw something

**着**(zháo)火: 
     Catch fire.

睡**着**(zháo)了: 
     Fall into sleep.

睡**着**(zhe)呢: 
     Sleeping.

**着**(zháo)急: 
     Worry.

站**着**(zhe): 
     Stand/Standing.

**着**(zhuó)实: 
     Indeed/Really.

附**着**(zhuó)：
     Attached to.

Answer (score 0):

我真的爱你：I love you truly.

我真的爱着你：I am in love with you truly.

他看我：He look at me.

他看了我：He looked me.

他看着我：He is looking at me.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add two more sentences to show the contrast cases.

(1) 哎，你踩着我的脚呢！踩着(zhe) means being standing on something. It is happening right now.

(2) 哎，你踩着我的脚了！踩着(zháo) means a fact that indeed happened. It may be in the past or at present.

Please see the following example too.

他的脚底下踩着一张百元钞票。(zhe)

今天出去散步，很不幸踩着狗屎了。(zháo)